# How to run a loop to export multiple files in R

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe

Please find below the code to run the loop. Here is the flow of loop:

1. To select output thrown by last line `a=sample_n(d.24,1)` and run the whole run again by using the selected output. i.e The new output *PAN* of LOOP 1 will become the new input *PAN* of LOOP 2 by changing the *PAN* Value for this line `tst_1=data.frame(CMP_PAN="AARCS0272Q")` from old to new PAN.
2. While running the loop , It should export csv file in incremental manner for the line `export(d.23,"cluster150.csv")`. So for loop 1 the export file will be *cluster1*, for loop 2 it will be *loop2*.
3. End of loop is till `nrow(d.24)==0`.

I can't share sample data as it quite confidential. Thank you in advance for this understanding.
I am not able to create the loop, so any help relate to approach or flow, will be a great help. I was looking for some reference in stack overflow but not able to find any.

```
cmp_data=read.delim("COM AND PAN 2.dat",sep=",", header = TRUE)
rel=read.delim("RELATIONSHIP 2.dat",sep=",",header = TRUE)
dir_data=read.delim("DIR PAN.dat",sep = ",",header = TRUE)

tst_1=data.frame(CMP_PAN="AARCS0272Q")
####CLUSTER-1
##LEVEL2
#TO GET COMPANY NAME
d.1=merge(tst_1,cmp_data,by="CMP_PAN")

# TO GET CONNECTED DIR_PAN
d.2=merge(d.1,rel,by="CMP_PAN",all.x = TRUE)

#TO GET COMPANY LINKED OF LINKED DIR_PAN
d.3=merge(d.2,rel,by="DIR_PAN",all.x = TRUE)

 #TO GET COMPANY NAMES
 d.4=merge(d.3,cmp_data,by.x ="CMP_PAN.y",by.y = "CMP_PAN")
  #PREPARING THE DATA
 d.5=data.frame(CMP_PAN1=d.4$CMP_PAN.x,
 CMP_NAME1=d.4$CMP_NAME.x,
 CMP_PAN2=d.4$CMP_PAN.y,CMP_NAME2=d.4$CMP_NAME.y)
 d.6=unique(d.5)
 d.6=d.6[order(d.6$CMP_PAN1),]

 ###LEVEL-3
 d.7=merge(d.6,rel,by.x = "CMP_PAN2",by.y = "CMP_PAN")
 d.8=merge(d.7,rel,by="DIR_PAN")
 d.9=merge(d.8,cmp_data,by="CMP_PAN")
 #PREPARING THE DATA
 d.10=data.frame(CMP_PAN1=d.9$CMP_PAN1,
 CMP_NAME1=d.9$CMP_NAME1,CMP_PAN2=d.9$CMP_PAN2,
 CMP_NAME2=d.9$CMP_NAME2,CMP_PAN3=d.9$CMP_PAN,CMP_NAME3=d.9$CMP_NAME)
 d.11=unique(d.10)
 d.11=d.11[order(d.11$CMP_PAN1),]
 d.12=data.frame(lapply(d.11,as.character),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
 d.12.p1=unique(d.12$CMP_PAN1)
 d.12.n1=unique(d.12$CMP_NAME1)
 d.12.p2=unique(d.12$CMP_PAN2)
 d.12.n2=unique(d.12$CMP_NAME2)
 d.12.p3=unique(d.12$CMP_PAN3)
 d.12.n3=unique(d.12$CMP_NAME3)
 max.len=max(length(d.12.p1),length(d.12.n1),
 length(d.12.p2),length(d.12.n2),length(d.12.p3),length(d.12.n3))
 d.13=data.frame(CMP_PAN1=c(d.12.p1,rep("",max.len-length(d.12.p1))),
            CMP_NAME1=c(d.12.n1,rep("",max.len-length(d.12.n1))),
            CMP_PAN2=c(d.12.p2,rep("",max.len-length(d.12.p2))),
            CMP_NAME2=c(d.12.n2,rep("",max.len-length(d.12.n2))),
            CMP_PAN3=c(d.12.p3,rep("",max.len-length(d.12.p3))),
            CMP_NAME3=c(d.12.n3,rep("",max.len-length(d.12.n3))))

  #export(d.13,"check3.csv")

  ###LEVEL -4
  d.14=merge(d.13,rel,by.x = "CMP_PAN3",by.y = "CMP_PAN")
  d.15=merge(d.14,rel,by="DIR_PAN")
  d.16=merge(d.15,cmp_data,by="CMP_PAN")
  #PREPARING THE DATA
  d.17=data.frame(CMP_PAN1=d.16$CMP_PAN1,CMP_NAME1=d.16$CMP_NAME1,
            CMP_PAN2=d.16$CMP_PAN2,CMP_NAME2=d.16$CMP_NAME2,
            CMP_PAN3=d.16$CMP_PAN3,CMP_NAME3=d.16$CMP_NAME3,
            CMP_PAN4=d.16$CMP_PAN,CMP_NAME4=d.16$CMP_NAME)
  d.17=unique(d.17)
  d.17=d.17[order(d.17$CMP_PAN1),]
  d.17=data.frame(lapply(d.17,as.character),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  d.17.p1=unique(d.17$CMP_PAN1)
  d.17.n1=unique(d.17$CMP_NAME1)
  d.17.p2=unique(d.17$CMP_PAN2)
  d.17.n2=unique(d.17$CMP_NAME2)
  d.17.p3=unique(d.17$CMP_PAN3)
  d.17.n3=unique(d.17$CMP_NAME3)
  d.17.p4=unique(d.17$CMP_PAN4)
  d.17.n4=unique(d.17$CMP_NAME4)
  max.len1=max(length(d.17.p1),length(d.17.n1),length(d.17.p2),
  length(d.17.n2),length(d.17.p3),length(d.17.n3),
         length(d.17.p4),length(d.17.n4))

  #export(d.17,"ch.csv")
  d.18=data.frame(CMP_PAN1=c(d.17.p1,rep("",max.len1-length(d.17.p1))),
            CMP_NAME1=c(d.17.n1,rep("",max.len1-length(d.17.n1))),
            CMP_PAN2=c(d.17.p2,rep("",max.len1-length(d.17.p2))),
            CMP_NAME2=c(d.17.n2,rep("",max.len1-length(d.17.n2))),
            CMP_PAN3=c(d.17.p3,rep("",max.len1-length(d.17.p3))),
            CMP_NAME3=c(d.17.n3,rep("",max.len1-length(d.17.n3))),
            CMP_PAN4=c(d.17.p4,rep("",max.len1-length(d.17.p4))),
            CMP_NAME4=c(d.17.n4,rep("",max.len1-length(d.17.n4))))

  ##LEVEL-5
  d.19=merge(d.18,rel,by.x = "CMP_PAN4",by.y = "CMP_PAN")
  d.20=merge(d.19,rel,by="DIR_PAN")
  d.21=merge(d.20,cmp_data,by="CMP_PAN")
  #PREPARING THE DATA
  d.22=data.frame(CMP_PAN1=d.21$CMP_PAN1,CMP_NAME1=d.21$CMP_NAME1,
            CMP_PAN2=d.21$CMP_PAN2,CMP_NAME2=d.21$CMP_NAME2,
            CMP_PAN3=d.21$CMP_PAN3,CMP_NAME3=d.21$CMP_NAME3,
            CMP_PAN4=d.21$CMP_PAN4,CMP_NAME4=d.21$CMP_NAME4,
            CMP_PAN5=d.21$CMP_PAN,CMP_NAME5=d.21$CMP_NAME)
  d.22=unique(d.22)
  d.22=d.22[order(d.22$CMP_PAN1),]
  d.22=data.frame(lapply(d.22,as.character),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  d.22.p1=unique(d.22$CMP_PAN1)
  d.22.n1=unique(d.22$CMP_NAME1)
  d.22.p2=unique(d.22$CMP_PAN2)
  d.22.n2=unique(d.22$CMP_NAME2)
  d.22.p3=unique(d.22$CMP_PAN3)
  d.22.n3=unique(d.22$CMP_NAME3)
  d.22.p4=unique(d.22$CMP_PAN4)
  d.22.n4=unique(d.22$CMP_NAME4)
  d.22.p5=unique(d.22$CMP_PAN5)
  d.22.n5=unique(d.22$CMP_NAME5)
  max.len2=max(length(d.22.p1),length(d.22.n1),length(d.22.p2),
  length(d.22.n2),length(d.22.p3),length(d.22.n3),
       length(d.22.p4),length(d.22.n4),length(d.22.p5),length(d.22.n5))

  d.23=data.frame(CMP_PAN1=c(d.22.p1,rep("",max.len2-length(d.22.p1))),
            CMP_NAME1=c(d.22.n1,rep("",max.len2-length(d.22.n1))),
            CMP_PAN2=c(d.22.p2,rep("",max.len2-length(d.22.p2))),
            CMP_NAME2=c(d.22.n2,rep("",max.len2-length(d.22.n2))),
            CMP_PAN3=c(d.22.p3,rep("",max.len2-length(d.22.p3))),
            CMP_NAME3=c(d.22.n3,rep("",max.len2-length(d.22.n3))),
            CMP_PAN4=c(d.22.p4,rep("",max.len2-length(d.22.p4))),
            CMP_NAME4=c(d.22.n4,rep("",max.len2-length(d.22.n4))),
            CMP_PAN5=c(d.22.p5,rep("",max.len2-length(d.22.p5))),
            CMP_NAME5=c(d.22.n5,rep("",max.len2-length(d.22.n5))))
   setwd("/Users/riskassessment/Desktop/COMPANY NETWORK/CLUSTER")
   export(d.23,"cluster150.csv")

   pan.x=data.frame(CMP_PAN=d.23$CMP_PAN5)  
   pan.y=rbind(pan1,pan.x)
   pan1=pan.y
   d.24=cmp_data[!cmp_data$CMP_PAN %in%
   pan1$CMP_PAN,]%>% select(CMP_PAN)

   a=sample_n(d.24,1)
   print(a)
```

Comment: Please STOP SHOUTING. Text in ALL CAPS is harder to read and understand, it won't get you help any faster, and it's extremely rude and annoying when you come here SHOUTING AND DEMANDING ATTENTION. When you see the list of questions on the main page, they're not in ALL CAPS for a reason - that's not acceptable conduct here. Please stop now.

Comment: @KenWhite: I am sorry if you felt that way. But I have no intension of shouting and demanding here for any reasons. I kept it all capital, just to highlight. Thanks for your insight, will keep that in mind next time.

Comment: Understood and Noted.Thanks